# Phabricator Audits across multiple git commits

Tags: git, phabricator

I have just set up a Phabricator server for our development team, and I love it already! To begin with we are only using it for code reviews. The UI far outperforms GitHub's commenting by lengths.

Anyhow, because I want to ease this into our team, I have decided to start out by using the Audit function instead of the Differentiator Review and Arcanist. I have set up a rule in Herald that triggers an audit for commits authored by anyone on our team, and then I assign the audits to the team, so anyone can pick up the audit.

This works ok, but I would like to be able to group audits as if I had squashed them before they were committed. As far as I can tell this is possible using Arcanist, but how do I do it using Audit?

I want to keep all the smaller commits in our git repo, but I would like to Audit them as one commit.

Comment: can you update what did you do?

Comment: Hi David, I added an answer below... but I have long since abandoned Phabricator. It was a cool product, but GitHub has evolved to a far superior product. So I use that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is, that this is not what audits are intended for.

Use Differential Reviews instead. They work so much better anyways, and don't be scared that they will make your workflow cumbersome. In my case all defaults for Arcanist turned out to fit perfectly.